# For what values of $p$ does $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x^p} \space dx$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Examine the convergence of  $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x^p}  \space dx $

$$\bigg| \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x^p}\bigg| \le \frac 1{x^p}        $$

Now $$ \int _0^1 \frac {dx}{x^p}     $$ is convergent for $p\ < 1$

So by comparisons test given integral is convergent for $p<1$

When $ 1\le p <2$

By the transformation $\frac 1x=u $

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x^p}\space dx=\int_1^{\infty} u^{p-2}\sin u \space du$$

Again the right integral is $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin u}{u^{2-p}} \space   du$

Let $\phi(u)=\frac 1{u^{2-p}}  $. Then $\phi$ is monotonic and bounded on $[1, \infty]$ and
$\displaystyle{\lim_{u \to \infty}}\phi(u)=0 $

The integral $\int_0^X \sin u \space du    $ is bounded on $[1,X] $ for all $X> 1$

Then the given integral is convergent for is convergent by Dirichlet's test when $ 1\le p <2$

When $p=2$ then it is divergent . But when $p>2$ , I have attempted to show the integral is divergent but without success (Like I tried to break the interval in $[2k\pi ,(2k+1)\pi]$ and get some inequality )

Please. Any hint regarding the case $p>2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p>2$. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\displaystyle u_n = \int_{\pi}^{n\pi} u^{p-2} \sin(u) du$.

Then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, one has
$$|u_{n+1}-u_n| = \left|\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} u^{p-2} \sin(u)  du \right| = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} u^{p-2}\left| \sin(u)\right|  du $$

(since $\sin$ keeps the same sign over $[n \pi, (n+1)\pi]$). So
$$|u_{n+1}-u_n| \geq (n\pi)^{p-2} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \left| \sin(u)\right|  du =2(n\pi)^{p-2}$$

In particular, $(|u_{n+1}-u_n|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not tend to $0$, and hence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ cannot converge.

Hence, the integral $\displaystyle \int_1^{+\infty} u^{p-2} \sin(u) du$ diverges, and by substitution,
$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{x^p} dx \text{ diverges}$$

Comment: Thanks as always:)